# how to elegantly .join() a string and a list?

Tags: python, string, list

I needed to join two strings:

```
In [1]: a = "hello"
In [2]: b = "world"
In [4]: ' '.join((a, b))
Out[4]: 'hello world'
```

Now that `b = ["nice", "world"]`, is there something more elegant than

```
In [7]: ' '.join((a, ' '.join(b)))
Out[7]: 'hello nice world'
```

to join all the elements (the string and the elements of the list) into a space delimited string?

Comment: wow, downvote & two closes. It would have been nice to point out what is wrong with that question...

Comment: Your solution is elegant and pythonic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [3]: ' '.join([a]+b)
Out[3]: 'hello nice world'
```

Or, if you are worried about the cost of creating an intermediate list, or if `b` isn't really a list at all, but some iterator:

```
In [9]: ' '.join(itertools.chain([a],b))
Out[9]: 'hello nice world'
```

Comment: both are excellent, more readable than the one I used, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use concatentation to join.

```
In [248]: a = "hello"

In [249]: b = ["nice", "world"]
In [252]: a + " " + ' '.join(b)
Out[252]: 'hello nice world'
```

Or simply use formatting the string.(if list is limited)

```
In [254]: '{0} {1} {2}'. format(a, b[0], b[1])
Out[254]: 'hello nice world'
```

Or [somehow better way](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) is:-

```
In [255]: '{0} {1[0]} {1[1]}'. format(a, b) 
Out[255]: 'hello nice world'
```

Comment: Yes, the list may grow, though (I do not know how large it will be) - thus the .join()

Comment: @WoJ if `b` grows then there is no issue in first solution as we just join the strings in list in `O(n)`.